# Externalization of strings from Storyboard in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I like to have all strings externalized from Storyboard to a strings file. There are two reasons for that.

Short term:

- I am not a native speaker and it helps me to give this file to somebody to review it and updated it.

Long term:

- It will help with internationalization.

I read how to [enable Base localization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html). I did that. However, I am still puzzled about two things

a) Why all the strings are still in a storyboard? I was expecting them to be replaced by some references to Main.strings file.

This bothers me. I can accidentally forget and change something in Main.storyboard. However it will be overwritten in runtime by the values from Main.strings file.

b) I may need to change UI in Storyboard and add some new places where strings should be used. How do I extract it to Main.strings. I know how to generate this file, but have no idea how to update it.

Comment: "This bothers me. I can accidentally forget and change something in Main.storyboard" Well don't. If you do, you'll have to regenerate the strings file. It doesn't happen magically by itself. However, this is awfully easy if you use the new `.xliff` generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more localizations, you should first add them into your project in project settings. Then you will be able to pick previously added localizations in storyboard properties and generate a .strings file for storyboard.

Each storyboard element (e.g. `UILabel`) has a storyboard Object ID (e.g. GSX-Yv-hAx). These IDs are referenced in storyboard .strings file. During instantiation of element from the storyboard its text is taken from the corresponding .strings file (if it is present) by its ID.

You should not modify keys in storyboard .strings file, as this will break reference of localized text to storyboard element.

Once you modify your storyboard (add new element), you would need to re-generate .strings file. You can do that by unchecking and checking again corresponding storyboard localization in storyboard properties. After that, you will have to merge the file with previous state.

Comment: So, the summary is "uncheck localiztion, check it again to generate a file and merge in changes which you had".. Wow... It looks like XCode has zero automation around localization.

Comment: Yes. And for Base localization - it is considered to be the actual state of the storyboard (e.g. text which you directly specify in the element), so Base localization you won't need to re-generate.